# automatic (user) input for command in shell script

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts

Issue:
I am writing an install script for setting up a machine.
At some point there is a user input required, like so:

```
chia keys add
# echo comes back: please enter 24 word mnemonic passphrase
hello this is an example mnemonic passphrase ... ... ... ... ...
```

likewise, another command requires userinput as well

```
chia wallet show
# echo comes back: No wallet file was found. To generate wallet, enter S
S
```

Question:
How can I automate these two user inputs in shell script?
Is it just a matter of writing these commands?

```
chia keys add
hello this is an example mnemonic passphrase ... ... ... ... ...
chia wallet show
s
```

Comment: Did you try IO redirection? For example `echo hello... | chia keys add` and `echo s | chia wallet show`. Also look at the command line options of the command `chia`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it was simply done with an Echo.

```
chia keys add
echo hello this is an example mnemonic passphrase ... ... ... ... ...
chia start wallet
echo S|chia wallet show
```